# Gmail Integration Using OAuth with .Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am looking to integrate Gmail API in our .Net project (Both Windows & Web) so that user can send email or read users inbox, their list of folders (i.e. labels) and their respective mail to import in to our system.

During my initial research through google api documentation; Below are couple of questions come across:

1. For OAuth 2.0; OAuth credential needs to be created for type of application in google api console. I wanted to create wrapper around Gmail API (i.e. MyGmailAPIClass) so that same class can be shared between my windows & web projects along with common OAuth mechanism.

   a.    Do I need to create separate OAuth credential for Windows & Web and hence the OAuth implementation will differ based on type of application?

   b.    Can we use the same OAuth Credential for different types of application like windows, web or mobile apps? If yes; how can we achieve that?
2. I came across Service Account Credential stuff; Can we use that for application to access users email for sending and retrieving? How can we achieve that?
3. For Access and Refresh token; if we don’t store in some file or database; user consent screen will be prompted every time when user come to our application next time? I am not able to figure out valid use case for storing in file or database. The reason why I asked this because when In .net console sample; I turned off that mechanism after first successful sign-in when I again run the console sample again it will not show consent screen for granting permission?

Please suggest how should i proceed !! It would be good if someone can give any direction and also reference some working example.

Comment: Using Net Default Credentials will use the User Account Mail properties to connect to the server.  The Username and Password are stored in the user account.  A window Admin can check these properties.

Comment: When you considered to create a [Gmail Editor Add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail) instead? Might be easier.

Comment: we wanted to use gmail api client library. could you tell us how **gmail editor add-on** or **NET default credential** approach help us here ?

Comment: in case of a gmail-addon each user that installs the add-on authorizes it with his credentials - so you won't have issues with authentication.